# attachBehaviors to rate button after ajax load

Tags: ajax, javascript, rating

I have a view that randomly loads two nodes with rate buttons. Once a rate button is clicked, I have it set to click the "next" pager to load another random view with ajax. However, after the first time ajax loads the new nodes, I get errors and then the rate-button reloads the whole page with a long string in the url.

I'm using drupal_add_js to add the following to the page.

```
(function($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.myRateButton = {   
    attach: function(context, settings) {
      $("a.rate-button").click(function() {
        $('li.pager-next a').click();
      });
    } 
  };
  Drupal.attachBehaviors("a.rate-button")
}(jQuery));
```

The error message is

```
An AJAX HTTP request terminated abnormally.
Debugging information follows.
Path: /views/ajax?page=1&rate[LONG STRING] 
StatusText: error
ResponseText: 
ReadyState: 0
```

Any pointers on what could be going wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do other AJAX features in your theme work?  Have you replaced jQuery with a newer version?

Comment: The same happens whether jQuery update is on or off. Ideally, I'd like this to work with jQuery 1.7+

Comment: And yeah, the ajax pager works every other time (the first time, and then fails, then works again after the rate button reloaded the whole page.)

Comment: Drupal.attachBehaviors(ID_OF_DIV_WRAPPER_WHICH_LOAD_AJAX_CONTENT)

Comment: Check [An AJAX HTTP request terminated abnormally alert in drupal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893188/an-ajax-http-request-terminated-abnormally-alert-in-drupal).